# How to display the result of Select query on list with ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, axios

I am new developer **ReactJS**, I develop a table with **ReactJS** on the FrontEnd, **NodeJS** on BackEnd and **MySQL** about the database.

I want when I click on the view button on Action column, it will be redirected to another page, which display a list containing the result of the Select query, as below :

[image]

ViewCLient.js :

```
class ViewClient extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            clients: [],
            Code :1111
        };
        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            activeTab: '1',
        };
    }

    toggle(tab) {
        if (this.state.activeTab !== tab) {
            this.setState({
                activeTab: tab,
            });
        }
    }
    componentDidMount(Code) {
        
        axios({
                method: "get",
                url: "/app/viewclient/"+Code  ,
                withCredentials: true,
                headers: {
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    Accept: "application/json"
                }
            })
            .then(response => {
                if (response && response.data) {
                    this.setState({ clients: response.data });
                }
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }

    render() {
        let { clients } = this.state;
       // let { clients } = this.state;
        return (
            <div className="animated fadeIn">
        <Row>
         
           <Col xs="12" md="6" className="mb-4">
            <Nav tabs>
              <NavItem>
                <NavLink
                  className={classnames({ active: this.state.activeTab === '1' })}
                  onClick={() => { this.toggle('1'); }}
                >
                  <i className="fa fa-info"></i> <span className={this.state.activeTab === '1' ? '' : 'd-none'}> Détails</span>
                </NavLink>
              </NavItem>
              <NavItem>
                <NavLink
                  className={classnames({ active: this.state.activeTab === '2' })}
                  onClick={() => { this.toggle('2'); }}
                >
                  <i className="fa fa-credit-card"></i> <span
                  className={this.state.activeTab === '2' ? '' : 'd-none'}> Factures</span>
                </NavLink>
              </NavItem>
              <NavItem>
                <NavLink
                  className={classnames({ active: this.state.activeTab === '3' })}
                  onClick={() => { this.toggle('3'); }}
                >
                  <i className="fa fa-truck"></i> <span className={this.state.activeTab === '3' ? '' : 'd-none'}> Bons de livraison</span>
                </NavLink>
              </NavItem>
            </Nav>
            <TabContent activeTab={this.state.activeTab} style={{ height:"420px"}}>
              <TabPane tabId="1">
               <ul>
               {
                       clients &&  clients.map(client => (
                            <li key={client.Code}>
                         <h1> Code client :    {client.Code} </h1>
                             {client.Prenom}
                              {client.Nom}
                              {client.FAX}
                             {client.Telephone}
                               {client.Email}
                                {client.Adresse1}
                                 {client.Adresse2}
               </li>
               ))}
               </ul>
              </TabPane>
              <TabPane tabId="2">
                
              </TabPane>
              <TabPane tabId="3">
              
              </TabPane>
            </TabContent>
          </Col>
          
        </Row>
      </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ViewClient;
```

ListClient.js

```
class ListeClients extends Component {


  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      clients: []
    };
    this.handleView = this.handleView.bind(this);
    this.handleEdit = this.handleEdit.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios({
        method: "get",
        url: "/app/listeclients/",
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Accept: "application/json"
        }
      })
      .then(response => {
        if (response && response.data) {
          this.setState({ clients: response.data });
        }
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

/*handleViewB(Code) {
   this.props.history.push('/clients/viewclient/');
}*/
handleView( evt) {
    try {
      console.log("Voir client")
      this.props.history.push('/clients/viewclient/');
      // Do something that could throw
    }
    catch (error) {
      this.setState({ error });
    }
  }
  handleEdit(event) {
    try {
    console.log("Modifier client")
    this.props.history.push('/clients/editclient/');
    // Do something that could throw
     } catch (error) {
       this.setState({ error });
     }
  }
  // event.preventDefault;





  render() {
    let { clients } = this.state;
     let Code = this.state;
    var btn = {
      backgroundColor: 'Transparent',
      backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
      border: 'none',
      cursor: 'pointer',
      overflow: 'hidden',
      outline: 'none'
    }
    var center = {
      textAlign: "center"
    }
    return (
      <div className="animated fadeIn">
       
          
            <Card style={{ height:"420px"}}>
              <CardHeader>
                <h4>
                  <strong>
                    <i className="fa fa-align-justify" /> Tous les clients
                  </strong>
                </h4>
              </CardHeader>
              <CardBody>
              
                    <Table  bordered responsive size="sm" style={center}>
                      <thead >
                        <tr>
                          <th ><strong>Code</strong></th>
                          <th>Prenom</th>
                          <th>Nom</th>
                          <th>Email</th>
                          <th>Telephone</th>
                          <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        {
                          clients.map(client => (
                            <tr key={client.Code}>
                              <td>{client.Code} </td>
                              <td>{client.Prenom}</td>
                              <td>{client.Nom}</td>
                              <td>{client.Email}</td>
                              <td>{client.Telephone}</td>
                              <td>
                                <button style={btn}   onClick={this.handleView} type="button"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>
                                <button style={btn} onClick={this.handleEdit} type="button"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
                                <button style={btn}><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          ))}
                      </tbody>
                    </Table>
              
              </CardBody>
            </Card>
         
        
         
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ListeClients;
```

My router.js :

```
exports.viewclient = function(req, res) {
  var Code = req.query.Code;
    console.log(req.params);

    connection.query('SELECT Code, Prenom, Nom, FAX, Telephone, Email, Adresse1, Adresse2  FROM clients  WHERE Code = ?',[req.params.Code],  function(error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        res.send(JSON.stringify(results));
console.log(results);
    });

}
```

My server.js :

```
router.get('/viewclient/:Code', clients.viewclient);
```

When I run the backend, it works well with *Postman*, but when I run it with **ReactJS**, it redirects me to `http://localhost:3000/app/viewclient/` but nothing is displayed and the console of the router `console.log(req.params)` returns `{ Code: 'undefined' }`

How to fix that please ?

Comment: Your React component fetch from '/app/viewclient/' which resolves to `http://localhost:300/app/viewclient/`. You need to pass the full url to axios.

Comment: Which url, it must be passed ?

Comment: check the answer of @madhu-bhat

Comment: @Christophe the issue  is about the url used on the frontend, that on axios on `ViewClients.js` or on `handleView` on `ListeClients.js`

Comment: Have you tried replacing `url: "/app/viewclient/"+Code` with `url: "http://localhost:4000/app/viewclient/"`?

Comment: Yes, but it's still the same issue ... Nothing is displayed on `http://localhost:3000/clients/viewclient/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The react app by default tries to connect to the url on port `3000`. So you would either need to provide the full url with port number on which the server is running (the url which you tried on Postman) to axios, or modify the `scripts` attribute of `package.json` to include the server port number.

Also, there the way of implementing componentDidMount in ViewClient.js is incorrect. In `componentDidMount(Code)`, `Code` will be undefined. If the value of `Code` will be constant, you can access the value within componentDidMount using the state. So change the same to below:

```
 componentDidMount() {

    axios({
            method: "get",
            url: "/app/viewclient/"+this.state.Code  ,
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                Accept: "application/json"
            }
        })
        .then(response => {
            if (response && response.data) {
                this.setState({ clients: response.data });
            }
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

Comment: I have an `"proxy": "http://localhost:4000/"` on my frontend and on my backend, I have `app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000/');`  I think the issue is about the url used on the frontend, that on `axios` on `ViewClients.js` or on `handleView` on `ListeClients.js`

Comment: `http://localhost:4000/app/viewclient/1111` returns `[{"Code":1111,"Prenom":"test","Nom":"test","FAX":"58985688888","Telephone":"58985699888","Email":"test@gmail.com","Adresse1":"","Adresse2":""}]`

Comment: Looks like the proxy that you set up isn't working, hence it's redirecting you to port 3000 itself instead of 4000. In which file have you added the proxy and could you share the same?

Comment: I added the proxy  `"proxy": "http://localhost:4000/"` on the file `package.json`

Comment: Can you please provide your complete `package.json`?

Comment: you can see the `package.json` here : https://gist.github.com/IchrakMansour/6e98028495e0de51309c98c55469c533

Comment: Your proxy looks fine.I guess there's a problem with the way you have implemented `componentDidMount` in `ViewClient.js`. Did you say that when you ran the react app, `console.log(req.params)` in the server logged `{ Code: 'undefined' }`?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please try the same and let me know.

Comment: Thank you @Mahu, it works when I put  `Code: props.match.params.Code` on constructor and  `axios.get('http://localhost:4000/app/viewclient/' + this.props.match.params.Code)` on `componentDidMount()`

Comment: Thank you @Madu Bhat, I did it, can you up the post ?

Comment: I cannot post anymore questions, how to resolve that  please ?

Comment: Sorry didn't get you @CodeLover. Isn't your issue resolved? You just said earlier that it works.